# How do I specify and end/expiration date for a Private Pass?

Tags: google-wallet

I don't see any documentation about a private pass end/expiration date.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

I'd like the information stored with the pass so the wallet app knows when to archive an item on it's own.

Thank you!

Comment: This might help you: it has a specific API endpoint which you can call to expire passes: https://github.com/google-wallet/rest-samples/blob/main/python/demo_eventticket.py#L473

Comment: This as well: https://developers.google.com/wallet/generic/use-cases/expired-passes